# How to fix "AssertionError: Value must be bytes" error in Python2.7 with Apache Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm new at Apache Kafka technology. I'm trying to send messages as JSON object to a kafka topic by using python 2.7 but i got "AssertionError: Value must be bytes" error. I can send messages as string succesfully, i can see my messages with kafka-console-consumer.sh. I'm using apache kafka 2.10-0.8.2.1 version. I'm giving my code below.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import yaml

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstap_servers="localhost:9092")
msg = yaml.safe_load('{"id":1, "name":"oguz"}')

producer.send("my-topic", msg)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`yaml.safe_load()` returns a dict, so there are two things required to turn it into bytes -- serialize it to a string via JSON, and then encode that to bytes as UTF-8.

Taken from the examples [in the kafka-python docs](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python#kafkaproducer), you can use the `value_serializer` keyword argument when you instantiate the `KafkaProducer`:

```
>>> import json
>>> producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
>>> producer.send('my-topic', msg)
```

Alternatively you could just serialize it manually when you call `send()`:

```
>>> producer.send('my-topic', json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8'))
```